# FeedMe error with iTunes RSS compatible feed

Tags: plugin-feedme, rss

I am trying to ingest an iTunes compatible RSS feed on the template with FeedMe... the enclosures have things like `<itunes:description>` in them. When I try and access these properties I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected).
```

Anyone know how I can access these enclosures without creating a Twig error?

Example current Twig code:

```
{{ feed[0].itunes:image['@href'] }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use dot syntax because of the colon, try this instead

```
{{ feed[0]['itunes:image']['@href'] }}
```